# Jquery DatePicker not working all dependencies included

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to setup Jquery UI `datepicker` but it's not working. I've made a demo of my setup here: https://jsfiddle.net/950g0oku/

The input field is

```
<input id="id_dates-0-starts" class="datetime field_required hasDatepicker" type="text" name="dates-0-starts">
```

and the javascript

```
$(".datetime").datepicker();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the class `hasDatepicker` from your field.

Take a look at this [updated version](https://jsfiddle.net/950g0oku/4/) of your fiddle (yours updated).

jQuery uses this class and it seems that if the class `hasDatepicker` is used the calendar's function does not show anything.

Hope it may helps

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the class `hasDatepicker` and now its working:

https://jsfiddle.net/950g0oku/3/

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the `hasDatepicker` class ? Remove it from your input and it works. Please see [the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mdv3bume/).

Fact is, jQuery-ui also use this classname, so when you use it, it seems there is a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `hasDatepicker` as a class name. This name is used by the jquery datepicker for rendering. please refer to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/glitson/950g0oku/5/)